# Why are two vectors that are parallel equivalent?

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus

Why are two parallel vectors with the same magnitude equivalent?

Why is their start point irrelevant?

How can a vector starting at $\,(0, -10)\,$ going to $\,(10, 0)\,$ be the same as 
a vector starting at $\,(10, 10)\,$ and going to $\,(20, 20)\,$?

Comment: The start point certainly *can* be relevant.  Imagine I choose to drop a rock either onto your foot or two feet away onto the floor. I suspect the start point for that force vector (both pointing down, with the same magnitude) will be important to you.

Comment: What *is* a vector? The answer to the question that’s posed must depend on your definition of “vector”. For me, a vector is not an arrow but something rather more abstract that is only described by an arrow. Others have different conceptions.

Comment: @Lubin can you elaborate on that?  That's kind of what my question was asking in a weird way. What is a vector?

Comment: Before anyone can tell you why it is "equivalent" you will have to tell us what YOU mean by "equivalent"!

Answer (score 2):

Vectors denote a direction and length, rather than start and end points. Sometimes they are called [*free* vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Overview). You can translate the start and end points of a vector by the same amount, and still get the same vector. To see why observe that for each coordinate we have $x_1-x_2 = (x_1+\Delta)-(x_2+\Delta)$. So two vectors with same direction & length are indistinguishable in that sense.

So two parallel vectors have the same direction. The direction of a vector $v = (x ,y)$ is given by the unit vector $u = (\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}, \dfrac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}})$ of length $1$. The example is 2D for simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

This is because both these vectors have the same magnitude and direction. Both may have different frames of reference, but for all computational purposes, they are identical. We have *centered* each vector by taking the starting point as the origin and retaining only the displacement with respect to that point.

However, if for examples, these vectors signify forces acting on a rigid (non-point mass) body, then they could result in different torques and hence have different meaning.

Answer (score -1):

Components of a vector determine the length and the direction of the vector, but not it's basepoint. Therefore 2 vectors are equivalent if and only if they have the same components, but this gives the idea that any 2 parallel vectors are equal though they have different base points. To avoid this confusion, we take that all vectors are based on the origin unless stated.